# CMake: How to store the SVN path in a variable?

Tags: svn, cmake

I am trying to store the output of the following command in a cmake variable:

```
svn info | grep URL | awk -F 'URL: ' '{ print $2}'
```

The purpose of using `awk` is to remove ULR: from the beginning of the output so that the final string would be a URL starting with `http`. Then I tried the following in the CMake file:

```
EXECUTE_PROCESS(
     COMMAND svn info ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
     COMMAND grep URL
     COMMAND awk -F 'URL: ' '{ print $2}'
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE SVNPATH
 )
```

But I got the following syntax error:

> awk: cmd. line:1: $2}'
>   awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ syntax error
>   awk: cmd. line:1: $2}'
>   awk: cmd. line:1:    ^ invalid char ''' in expression

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code seems to work for me, can you try it out? (of course, replace `echo` with `svn info`)

```
EXECUTE_PROCESS(
     COMMAND echo "URL: http://blabla"
     COMMAND grep URL
     COMMAND awk -F "URL: " "{print $2}"
     OUTPUT_VARIABLE SVNPATH
)

MESSAGE(STATUS "EXEC: ${SVNPATH}")
```